# how to change dataTable page display results and maxmum result's

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

In MySQL I hv fetched morethan 100 rows which is a default limit display results of DataTables.
I would like to override the default limit of Datatables and show 30 rows on each page up to the end of my MySQL results I have fetched.
In MySQL I am fetching all data which matches specified month

Comment: Please show some code

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = $( ".datatable-1" ).DataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 30});
```

Comment: cannot reinitiate datatable, if you want to retrieve data from this object pass no argument or see docs for bRetrive and bDestory 
that's the error am getting